# No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/joaom/Downloads/ABCB' but it exists

Tags: python, file, directory, shutil

I'm trying to move files on python from my downloads folder into my GitHub project folder.
I'm using the shutil method :

```
import shutil 
source = 'C:/Users/joaom/Downloads/ABCB'
destination = 'C:/Users/joaom/OneDrive/Documentos/GitHub/Snp1000/Performance Tables'
dest = shutil.move(source, destination)
```

but I get always some for of the same error:

```
FileNotFoundError: 

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/joaom/Downloads/ABCB'
```

I have tried using r strings, double quotes, \ slashes, double slashes but still, get the same error, and I'm just wondering what else to do.
The code above, if I paste the destination or source paths on my file explorer I get to the right place so a bit unsure

Comment: Have you tried a relative path? (does `~` expand under windows?) This would rule out permission issues, if successful.

Comment: Try to:  r'C:/Users/joaom/Downloads/ABCB'

Comment: @VictorSaraivaRocha what difference would that make? A raw string doesn't affect forward-slashes.

Comment: You are right Pranav, thanks.

@user15464793, maybe is because you didn't expecify the extension of files, something like that:
source = 'C:/Users/joaom/Downloads/ABCB.txt'
destination = 'C:/Users/joaom/OneDrive/Documentos/GitHub/Snp1000/Performance/ Tables'/ABCB.txt

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to copy the file **ABCB** so specify the extension of it. According to the line `source = 'C:/Users/joaom/Downloads/ABCB'` ABCB is a folder that is missing in your Downloads folder.

Comment: Files may have no extension.